# Export CSV from Neo4j to AWS S3 failed

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to Export data from cypher query to S3 with APOC Export

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH (a:Person) RETURN  a.name as name",
"s3://s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/testeneo4j/exports/neo4j_test.csv?accessKey=<accessKey>&secretKey=<secretKey>", {})
```

I did the plugins downloads:

- aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.250.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.250)
- aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.250.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-s3/1.11.250)
- httpclient-4.4.8.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.4)
- httpcore-4.5.4.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.8)
- joda-time-2.9.9.jar (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9)

And I set the apoc.export.file.enabled=true.

After that I've got the next error:

```
Failed to invoke procedure apoc.export.csv.query: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder
```

[Error Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW62U.png)

I couldn't find any details on this error, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to download and copy the apoc jar file to plugins folder.

> Here is apoc [ver 4.1.0.6](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/4.1.0.6/apoc-4.1.0.6-all.jar)

> Copy it to your $HOME_NEO4J/plugins/ directory.
> Also, please ensure that you set this in neo4j.conf config file:  **apoc.export.file.enabled=true** then do a restart

APOC is not included when you install neo4j, so you need to copy it.

Comment: I've set the path with all plugins and set the apoc.export.file.enabled=true but 
still not working.